# Is it possible to get SECOND battery charge level for tablet device?

Tags: android, tablet, batterylevel

Some android tablets come with 2 batteries installed. A good [example](http://www.asus.com/Tablets_Mobile/The_New_ASUS_Transformer_PadTF701T/) is Asus Transformer family - second battery is installed into detachable keyboard. Is there a way to get charge level (from code) of that battery in keyboard? Is there any general API of getting this level for second battery in android device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any general API of getting this level for second battery in android device?

Nothing in the Android SDK. Manufacturers might expose this data in one way or another (e.g., additional extras on `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` broadcasts), and there may be a way to get the 2nd battery level through approaches that you might use on a Linux machine (e.g., stuff in `/sys`).